# Showing that $f(z):C \to C$ is holomorphic on all of C\0 then $\int_{\partial B_r(0)}f(z) dz $ Is independent of r

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Hi I must show that $f:\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ is holomorphic on all of $\Bbb C\setminus0$ then $$\int_{\partial B_r(0)}f(z) dz $$ is independent of $r$.

I know for a function to be holomorphic it has a primitive, is on an open set, and is piecewise. But that's all I know, I would be appreciative for any extra help.

Comment: Actually, many holomorphic functions do not have primitives.

Comment: Apply the Cauchy theorem (residue version) to the annulus between two circles - as the function is holomorphic there, the integrals on the two circles are the same since there are no residues to be picked up in the annulus